# Can non-exile related return effects bring a card out of exile?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So I stumbled upon this land, [Karakas](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Karakas).  Can this return effect reach a card in exile?  I read the rules regarding exile, and it appears to me that Karakas' effect (and similar return/play/add effects) are fully capable of accessing the Exile Zone.

Comment: Related: the first section of this article talks about why there aren't really cards that can do this: http://archive.wizards.com/Magic/magazine/Article.aspx?x=mtg/daily/mm/194

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Karakas' ability:

> Tap: Return target legendary creature to its owner's hand.

Karakas returns a *creature*. Creatures only exist on the battlefield, everywhere else they are usually creature *cards* (or spells, on the stack).

> 109.2. If a spell or ability uses a description of an object that includes a card type or subtype, but doesn't include the word "card," "spell," "source," or "scheme," it means a permanent of that card type or subtype on the battlefield.

So Karakas can not target cards in exile.

Answer (score 5):

No, it can't. Only cards that explicitly state that they can return something from exile can do so. Examples are very few.

- [Riftsweeper](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Riftsweeper) returns an arbitrary face up exiled card to library.
- [Misthollow Griffin](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Misthollow%20Griffin) can be cast from exile.
- [Torrent Elemental](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Torrent%20Elemental) can be brought back from exile.
- [Pull from Eternity](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Pull%20from%20Eternity) returns an arbitrary face up exiled card to it's graveyard.
- [Mirror of Fate](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mirror%20of%20Fate) swaps your library for 7 exiled cards (any order)
- [Runic Repetition](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Runic%20Repetition) returns an exiled flashback card to your hand.
- [Venser Diffusion](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Venser%20Diffusion) returns a suspended (i.e. temporarily exiled) card to it's owner's hand.

As Jefromi points out in a comment to the answer, Mark Rosewater is not too interested in seeing this as a mechanic that gets deeply developed, because it then becomes a second graveyard. [Link](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/gle-ladies-part-3-2012-05-07)

Note: There are on the order of 30 cards that exile cards face down.  Here's a rough search for them on gatherer:  [http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=+[exile]+[face]+[down]](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=+%5Bexile%5D+%5Bface%5D+%5Bdown%5D)

Comment: The only other two I've seen are Pull from Eternity and Mirror of Fate, but Mirror of Fate is almost always a bad idea.  Unless you happen to have a Laboratory Maniac handy.

Comment: Well that sounds like a legit plan. Of course Doomsday could do that easier...

Comment: Runic Repetition is probably the other thing that should be on that list. (It's restricted to cards with flashback, though.)

Comment: Venser's Diffusion can also unexile exiled cards, but only if they're currently suspended.

Comment: In Battle for Zendikar, it looks like this might become a more common mechanic. For instance, Oblivion Sower can pull your opponent's lands out of exile: http://media.wizards.com/2015/images/daily/EN_jkt2vsve7u.png

Comment: There are a lot more cards that return cards in exile, as long as they were the ones that exiled them in the first place.